# Selenium webdriver (Javascript) and phantomjs wait for element to be located does not work

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

```
var phantom = require('phantomjs-server');
const By = require('selenium-webdriver').By;

driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.css(".button1")), 30000);

var quoteButton = driver.findElement(By.css(".button1"));
quoteButton.click();
```

Taking screenshot after wait condition shows that button1 is not there in screenshot. Still the test moves onto next step of clicking the button. I get an error:

```
ElementNotVisibleError: {"errorMessage":"Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated","request":{"headers":{"Accept":"application/json; charset=utf-8","Connection":"close","Content-Length":"2","Content-Type":"application/json;charset=UTF-8","Host":"127.0.0.1:4444"},"httpVersion":"1.1","method":"POST","post":"{}","url":"/click","urlParsed":{"anchor":"","query":"","file":"click","directory":"/","path":"/click","relative":"/click","port":"","host":"","password":"","user":"","userInfo":"","authority":"","protocol":"","source":"/click","queryKey":{},"chunks":["click"]},"urlOriginal":"/session/5e123bd0-fb66-11e5-8858-123/element/:wdc:1459885290612/click"}}
```

Comment: please verify that if is elementLocated(By.css(".button1")) points to more then one web element on the page

Comment: I have tried By.xpath("//button[@class='btn1'][@type='submit'][contains(text(),'GET QUOTE')]") which shows only one element on the page and I still get the error

Comment: Stopped using phantomjs. Going to use mocha, selenium-webdriver.

Comment: if u already know javacript why don't you try seleniumjs -protractor